# Ожидание результата выполнения

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Всем привет!

Нужна помощь, есть функция:

```
scanNetwork() {
    fetchJSON(`/devs.ip?st=1`).then(ipList => {
        for (let i in ipList) {
            let ip = ipList[i].STAip;
            // Собираем данных с каждого устройства
        }
        fetchJSON(`/devs.ip?st=0`)
    });
}
```

В цикле for происходит формирование данных, которые нужны в будущем.

Как сделать так, что бы строчка fetchJSON(`/devs.ip?st=0`) вызывалась именно по завершению цикла for, а не асинхронно?

Comment: async await либо обернуть всё в промис

Comment: А как это через Promise сделать? Я только учусь, не могу сообразить как правильно.

Comment: Хотя попробуй так:

`scanNetwork() {
    fetchJSON(`/devs.ip?st=1`).then(ipList => {
        for (let i in ipList) {
            let ip = ipList[i].STAip;
            // Собираем данных с каждого устройства
        }
    }).then(fetchJSON(`/devs.ip?st=0`));
}`

Попробуй так сделать, если не получится, кури эти:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/209662/
https://learn.javascript.ru/promise

Comment: Не работает так как выше